# Get records from last 7 days

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have problem with query

```
SELECT
    IFNULL(SUM(a.x), 0) AS x,
    IFNULL(COUNT(*), 0) AS num
FROM a AS a
WHERE (a.`time` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY))
GROUP BY DAY(a.time)
```

It's ok, but when exact day have no records this no return this day. I need to return 0. 
How to do it?

Comment: you want mysql to make thing up and rerun data when there is none?

Comment: if there is no record for the day, database will not return a record for that day, thats pretty straightforward. you need to handle this requirement as you process the data or display it.

Comment: this link may help you 
[get records from last 7 days ][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804563/return-records-for-last-n-days-when-not-every-day-in-n-has-a-record

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(SUM(a.x), 0) AS x,
    COALESCE(COUNT(*), 0) AS num
FROM a AS a
WHERE (a.`time` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY))
GROUP BY DAY(a.time)
```

[COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) - returns the first non-null value in the list

But, I think you should handle this as you process the data as suggested by @DevZer0.

Comment: That approach returns, like OP's approach doesn't return 0 when the day has no records